# Updating UITableViewCell constraints causes exception

Tags: ios, constraints, tableview, autolayout

I'm using Xcode 5 with the iOS 7 SDK. I have a UITableViewCell defined as a prototype in my storyboard and I'm using autolayout for the subviews within the cell. When the cell is requested by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I populate the cell with its data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ActivityTableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Activity"];
    Activity *activity = self.activities[(NSUInteger)indexPath.row];

    [tableViewCell configureWithActivity:activity];

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

This data can cause the height of one of the subviews to change. I am changing the subview's height by modifying its constraint, along with other constraint modifications:

```
@implementation ActivityTableViewCell

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    // Update constraints based on the activity
    self.activityDocumentsTableViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = ...;
    self.betweenActivityDocumentsTableViewAndNotesLabelLayoutConstraint.constant = ...;
    self.activityNotesTableViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = ...;
    self.betweenActivityNotesTableViewAndContentViewLayoutConstraint.constant = ...;

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void)configureWithActivity:(Activity *)activity
{
    // Populate subviews using the activity variable

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

@end
```

My ActivityTableViewCell class derives from another class that tells the content view to automatically size to fit its dynamically-sized subviews:

```
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

My view controller pre-calculates the heights of all of these cells and stores them in an array. Those heights are supplied in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

All of this works perfectly, until I scroll the table view:

```
2014-01-17 10:41:47.435 ... Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4a520 UnknownLabel:0x13c4a440.height == 26>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4ad20 BorderedTableView:0xd46e000.height == 54>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4b800 UnknownLabel:0x13c4b720.height == 26>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4be40 BorderedTableView:0xd462600.height == 74>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4cc60 BorderedTableView:0xd46e000.top == UnknownLabel:0x13c4a440.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4ccc0 BorderedTableView:0xd462600.top == UnknownLabel:0x13c4b720.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4cd20 UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c49de0.bottom == BorderedTableView:0xd462600.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4cd50 UnknownLabel:0x13c4a440.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c49de0.top + 20>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4cd80 UnknownLabel:0x13c4b720.top == BorderedTableView:0xd46e000.bottom + 55>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xb2c1bf0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x13c49de0.height == UITableViewCellScrollView:0x13c4d000.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xb2c2460 UITableViewCellScrollView:0x13c4d000.height == ActivityTableViewCell:0x13c49be0.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x13935110 ActivityTableViewCell:0x13c49be0.height == 318>"
)
```

Note that the sum of all the vertical constants does *not* total 318, thus the exception. The 318 is coming from my pre-calculated height and is the correct height for this cell. However, the fourth constraint in that exception,  `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13c4be40 BorderedTableView:0xd462600.height == 74>"`, is incorrect (it *was* correct the first time this cell was dequeued and configured). That's because iOS appears to be applying the row height *before* calling my cell's `updateConstraints` method, which itself updates that fourth constraint to its correct value.

I have tried numerous combinations of calling `updateConstraints`, `setNeedsLayout`, etc., all to no avail. I simply cannot figure out how to prevent iOS from updating the autoresizing mask *before* my constraints have been updated. The good news is that *after* `updateConstraints` is called--and it eventually is--the constraints seem to work; I see my cell correctly and the size of all the subviews appears correct. I just don't like seeing these exceptions in the console and I'd prefer to eliminate them if possible.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929221/uitableview-when-changing-constraint-which-effects-height-of-cell-after-dequeuei.  Did you happen to ever resolve this?

Comment: It's been awhile since I worked on that application, but no, I never did find a suitable workaround. :(

Answer (score 0):

Really no clean solution that I've found, other than changing the priority to 999 on one of the vertical constraints.  This will eliminate the error message itself.